# Shipping part of Python standard library

Tags: python, anki

How do I ship some standard modules from Python together with my code?

I'm writing an add-on for Anki, for which I need `Queue` and `threading` modules from `Python2.7` standard library.

When I try launching Anki, I get `ImportError: No module named Queue`. I assume that is because Anki does not ship with full Python interpreter and if I am missing any standard modules, I am to bundle them myself.

From Anki [docs on addons](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/addons.html#standard-modules):

> Standard Modules
>
> Anki ships with only the standard modules necessary to run the program
>   - a full copy of Python is not included. For that reason, if you need to use a standard module that is not included with Anki, you’ll need
>   to bundle it with your add-on.

So my question is: what steps do I take to bundle standard Python modules `threading` and `Queue` together with my add-on?

Note that add-ons in Anki are just Python scripts that have certain extra modules available.

Comment: Same problem, it's really frustrating.

Comment: Hey, did my answer solve your problem? If so, could you mark my solution as the correct one? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the Anki doc:

> For a simple one-file add-on, you can upload the .py file. For multi-file add-ons, please create a subfolder that acts as a Python package, and create a small .py file that imports that package. Using the Japanese support add-on as an example, the structure looks like:
>
> ```
> japanese/file1.py
> japanese/file2.py
> japanese/__init__.py # can be empty; marks the folder as a package
> japanese/<binary support files>
> jp.py
> ```
>
> To upload a multi-file add-on, please zip up the folder and the loader .py file and upload the zip.

The `<binary support files>` can be the modules you want.

Checkout [html_cleaner](https://github.com/glutanimate/html-cleaner) and [image-occlusion-enhanced](https://github.com/glutanimate/image-occlusion-enhanced)
 on Github if you want to see how others do it.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else who is wondering how to import a .so file (I was using a library that tried to `import parser` and discovered that `parser.__file__` was a .so file) the answer is it's the same as a .py file:

Create a directory (`mkdir parser`), copy the .so file into that directory (`cp parser.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so parser/`) and then add an `__init__.py` to the directory (`touch parser/__init__.py`).

This is almost certainly *not* cross platform, but it worked for my needs.