# Anki (SRS software) addon packages/modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, anki

I am writing my own add on for the SRS Anki (2.1x).

My script works outside of Anki, but I want to run it from the toolbar in Anki to act on cards called by Anki.

I keep getting errors saying that the modules I am importing (such as pygame) are missing.

I have done as Giorgan Borca-Tasciuc suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44556065/shipping-part-of-python-standard-library)

and included the folders with the module files and **init**.py files to scan the folders. So for example, I have the folder 'pygame' inside the same folder as the folder that represents the addon script. Both have **init**.py files in.

However, it always seems to find some module that isn't imported. For example, now it can't find the built-in Python package 'array'.

I have also tried to hack this with lines in my addon script such as:

```
sys.path.append('/Users/user/AnacondaProjects/Anki/')
sys.path.append('/Users/user/Library/Application%20Support/Anki2/addons21/playback/')
sys.path.append('/Users/user/Library/Application%20Support/Anki2/addons21/playback/pygame')
sys.path.append('/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages')
```

Surely I don't have to include every possible module that every sub file uses.

What am I doing wrong?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/addons.html#standard-modules):

> ### Standard Modules
>
> Anki ships with only the standard modules necessary to run the program - a full copy of Python is not included. For that reason, if you need to use a standard module that is not included with Anki, you’ll need to bundle it with your add-on.

Now, how do you bundle add-ons? [The documentation](https://apps.ankiweb.net/docs/addons.html#sharing-add-ons) says:

> ### Sharing Add-ons
>
> For a simple one-file add-on, you can upload the .py file. For multi-file add-ons, please create a subfolder that acts as a Python package, and create a small .py file that imports that package. Using the Japanese support add-on as an example, the structure looks like:
>
> ```
> japanese/file1.py
> japanese/file2.py
> japanese/__init__.py # can be empty; marks the folder as a package
> japanese/<binary support files>
> jp.py
> ```
>
> To upload a multi-file add-on, please zip up the folder and the loader .py file and upload the zip.

So you should place the modules you require in a support folder, and import them from there. Something like:

```
myaddon/pygame.zip
myaddon/__init__.py
ma.py
```

`ma.py` can be a sort of configure-and-load-`myaddon` file, and `__init__.py` (`myaddon` proper) can `from . import pygame`.

Comment: Hello, I followed the Anki support and still had the error listed above.

I don't really understand what you mean by:



    ma.py can be a sort of configure-and-load-myaddon file, and __init__.py (myaddon proper) can from . import pygame.

Comment: @SebSilas Make the modules you need submodules of your addon package. Read [the Python tutorial page on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) to understand.

Comment: I've done all this but couldn't get it to work. I'll paste my code soon

Answer (score 0):

Share an experience that imports BeautifulSoup from bs4. Hope to help you.

Downloading beautifulsoup4 source code, unzip the code and copy the "bs4" folder to Anki Add-On folder `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Anki2\addons\`. Then restart Anki. My akPlugin.py script can find BeautifulSoup from bs4.

```
λ ls -al addons
total 56
drwxr-xr-x 1 Admin 197121     0 Aug 30 09:12 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 Admin 197121     0 Oct 22 18:28 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 Admin 197121 37794 Jul 18 10:11 akPlugin.py
drwxr-xr-x 1 Admin 197121     0 Sep 29  2015 bs4/
```